# How to schedule a Cron job for the second to the last day of each month

Tags: centos, cron, shell-scripting

I want to schedule a task for the second to the last day of each month. I have read [this great article](http://blog.nexcess.net/2013/05/09/cron-job-for-the-last-day-of-the-month/) about shell scripting the execution. I have also seen that you can use "L" to represent the last day of the month, but I am using [CentOS and cannot use the "L" construct](https://serverfault.com/questions/265879/cron-job-that-runs-on-the-last-monday-of-the-month).

I want to run the task at 11PM on the second to last day of each month. I hope to construct a command similar to:

```
0 23 27-30 * * [ &quot;$(date +%d -d tomorrow&quot; = &quot;L&quot; ] &amp;&amp; $HOME/path/to/script
```

Knowing that I can't use L to represent the last day of the month, how can I use this logic to schedule my Cron job?

Comment: To anybody wanting to edit this question: The broken HTML is actually a part of the reason the crontab isn't working; by fixing them **in the question** you're mangling it.

Comment: Suggest to use "31", some month is 31 days long. It won't be called on 31. day of january, for example.

Comment: @PeterHorvath Please stop changing the content of the question. The broken HTML is actually part of the problem.

Comment: @JennyD Sorry, maybe I didn't follow the exact situation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The code samples on that site are erroneous. They have certain shell characters replaced with HTML entities. The quotes also seem to be in the wrong places. I wonder if the author ever looked at that page when writing it...

Once we fix that, and then check to see if the first of the month is in *two* days rather than one...

```
0 23 27-30 * * [ $(date +\%d -d "2 days") == 01 ] && /where/is/my/script
```